# How to find multiple spaces inside text for a varchar2 field in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I don't recall ever seeing a field like this before, but it combines the city, state, and zipcode into a single string of varchar2.  Fortunately, I believe most of the fields are in the same city space state, space zipcode format, but I started finding a few that deviated from that norm.

Right now I'm trying to identify all these distinct conditions
in the database with over 5 million rows and my queries aren't working for what I wanted.

I started with:

```
SELECT PROJECT_CTY_ST_ZIP FROM PAYMENT WHERE PROJECT_CTY_ST_ZIP LIKE '%' || CHR(32) || '%';
```

Then tried:

```
SELECT PROJECT_CTY_ST_ZIP FROM PAYMENT WHERE PROJECT_CTY_ST_ZIP LIKE '% %' AND PROJECT_CTY_ST_ZIP LIKE '% %'  AND PROJECT_CTY_ST_ZIP LIKE '% %';
```

but they are both pulling based on leading and trailing spaces and I was really wanted to find spaces in the inside of the text.  I don't want to remove them, just identify them with a query so I can parse them properly in my java code and then do an insert later to put them into city, state, and zipcode fields in another table.

While it doesn't show it here, I found this field in IA with no leading spaces, then one leading space and then two leading spaces.  I fixed the leading spaces with trim.

WEST LIBERTY, IA 52776

This last one I wasn't expecting and I wanted to see if there are other conditions that might be unusual, but my query doesn't find them as the spaces are in the middle of the text:

**TRUTH OR CONSEQUENCE, NM 87901**

How would I go about a query to find these kinds of distinct records?

Comment: In your 2nd query attempt, you appear to be checking against the same column 3 times in the same way.  Is that a typo?

Comment: you write a whole story but still if you add Expected output for some sample data, thats will be great. Come directly on point

Comment: No, I was attempting to do a kind of && condition like in java.  As far as the expected output, I'm just trying to find city names that have multiple spaces in their name, like TRUTH OR CONSEQUENCE NM.  I don't know what else I could find perse, but I'm concerned I'll find similar ones like Big Rock Candy Mountain, VT and I need to be able to make my parsing dynamic enough to handle them.  Hence the query.

Comment: @James: Be more precise if possible.  Are you looking for an exact number of spaces within the string value?  Do you want to ignore spaces at the beginning and end of the value?  What if you find 2 contiguous spaces within the string? etc.

Comment: I'm attempting to find out what other city, state, zip fields that I will have to parse in my java code and try to improve it, based on what I find. I don't know if there are 2 contigious spaces or 2 or more like the NM example.  Just trying to find them, not replace them.  I hope that makes sense.  Like I said, I've never worked with a database that combines these 3 fields into one, to me that is a poor design, but their must have been a valid use case for it.  At lease I hope so.  I have to work with it in any case.  If its really not a good question I can delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query replaces each of the spaces with a dot (.) so you can see them

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(PROJECT_CTY_ST_ZIP,
                 '([[:space:]])',
                 '.') spaces_or_now_dots
  FROM PAYMENT
```

This query finds the ones that have one or more spaces.

```
  SELECT PROJECT_CTY_ST_ZIP
  FROM PAYMENT   
  where REGEXP_LIKE(PROJECT_CTY_ST_ZIP,
                 '[[:space:]]'
                 )
```

I have not considered the cases of spaces in the beginning and end, because you have already taken care of them.

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for.  I hadn't worked with the REGXP in Oracle before.  Thanks!